# Plotting a Damped Cosine Function using Openframeworks

Tags: openframeworks

Recently we were told in class to work on an assignment in which we were supposed to plot some engineering functions. There were several of them, so I am only taking the cosine one as an example.
We were supposed to write and call several functions that would take real life coordinates and then map them into pixel coordinates, as well as get y values based on given arrays of x values.
I think I did okay with the functions, but now that they are all written out, I have no idea what function to use in draw to be able to actually draw this cosine function.
I basically want an advice on how I can go ahead and call those functions properly in what draw function to be able to just map this cosine curve. I will appreciate any help I can get.

I tried using ofDrawCurve function to plot the points, but it is not letting me use my arrays in the argument list. ofXPlotter did not seem to work either, although I am not entirely sure I used it properly.

Here are my functions for plotting points and mapping:

```
        int getXSamples(float xmin, float xmax, float step, float x[])
{
int n;
n = (xmax - xmin) / step + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    x[i] = xmin + i * step;
}
return n;
}

void getDampedCosSamples(int n, float x[], float y[], float alpha, float w)
{

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    y[i] = exp(-alpha * x[i])*cos(w*x[i]);
}

}

void getGaussianSamples(int n, float x[], float y[], float alpha, float mu)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    y[i] = exp(-alpha * (x[i] - mu)*(x[i] - mu));
}

}
void getSincSamples(int n, float x[], float y[], float alpha)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    y[i] = (sin(alpha*PI*x[i]) / (alpha*PI*x[i]));
}

}
float map(float in, float inMin, float inMax, float outMin, float outMax)
{
float m, b, out;

m = (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin);
b = outMax - m * inMax;
out = m * in + b;
return(out);
}
void map_vec(int n, float in[], float out[], float inMin, float inMax, float outMin, float outMax)
{
float m, b;

m = (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin);
b = outMax - m * inMax;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    out[i] = m * in[i] + b;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying arrays inside the function, but the effects are not taking place outside of it.

Try passing as an argument a pointer to an array, or returning the array which contains the points you want to see drawn.

Then use an ofPath, or [ofPolyline](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofPolyline/) to store those points.

For example :

```
void getGaussianSamples(int n, float x[], float y[], float alpha, float mu)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    y[i] = exp(-alpha * (x[i] - mu)*(x[i] - mu));
}
```

would be rewriten like this :

```
std::vector < float > getGaussianSamples(int n, float x[], float alpha, float mu){
// this way the size of y doesn't have top be initialised 
std::vector < float > arrayY;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    float currentY = exp(-alpha * (x[i] - mu)*(x[i] - mu));
    arrayY.push_back(currentY);
}
return arrayY;
}
```

then declare a polyline and the array Y in ofApp.h::setup() :

```
ofPolyline poly
std::vector < float > y;
```

then in ofApp.cpp::setup() :

```
// n, x, alpha, mu all have to be declared somewhere
y = getGaussianSamples(n, x, alpha, mu);
for( int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){
poly.addVertex(ofVec3f(y[i].x, y[i].y, 0));
}
```

in ofApp.cpp::draw() :

```
// styling only for this polyline
ofPushStyle();
// color is red
ofSetColor(255, 0, 0);
poly.draw();
ofPopStyle();
```